# How to avoid code duplication for JMS Messages classes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jms, messaging

I'm new to JMS and JavaEE and I'm supposed to implement an enterprise application where communication between modules happens via JMS using a (non-trivial) common data model.

I've been reading a book and documentation but I don't understand how I'm supposed to share the message interface (or schema) between different modules.

Let's say I have an `AppCommonDataModelDocument` object that I serialize to XML with JAXB and send as a message on a JMS queue, how can the receiver deserialize it? I guess it has to have the same class(es) in its classpath.

So am I supposed to copy the `AppCommonDataModelDocument` to each module?
How do I manage changes to it?
With WebService we have WSDL that define the message format, is there something like that for Messaging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate module containing the shared message classes, and add a dependency on that shared module in all the modules that need to serialize/deserialize instances of those classes.

Comment: Does this work with different EARs too? I might have to split the application in two different EARs

Comment: I don't understand how the classpath works in javaee yet, that's why I'm asking.